# Use-case of Android Lifecycle functions onRestoreInstanceState, onSaveInstanceState

Tags: android, android-activity, viewmodel, lifecycle, use-case

I recently wrote a demo app, which just needed to display some data temporarily --- I meant for the data to disappear once the app was properly destroyed by the user.  Toward this, I read the page
[The Activity Lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle) , which seems to recommend overriding the Activity methods
`onRestoreInstanceState()` and `onSaveInstanceState()`.

It worked great! The data was preserved through screen rotations, and sending the app to the background.

But then I would leave the app running and walk away, and when I looked at it again, the data was gone.

I spent hours trying to de-bug my app, and re-reading that page.

Finally, I read
[Saving UI States](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/saving-states).  It refers to overriding these methods as "ViewModel" approach, and explicitly states that data saved this way does not survive system-initiated process death --- which explains my observation.

My main question is:  what on earth is the practical application of this "ViewModel" persistence approach?  What is the use-case for a persistence mechanism that randomly disposes of data when the user isn't looking?

(I guess this is an old API left over from the times when apps didn't run in the background.  But I don't see that reflected in the documentation.)

A second question is, reading the first page, how on earth was I supposed to understand this unfortunate behavior?  Did I miss something?  (It is very long.)

Answer (score 2):

> what on earth is the practical application of this "ViewModel" persistence approach?

It is not a persistence approach. A `ViewModel` is a way of holding onto state across [configuration changes](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes). Using a `SavedStateHandle` with `ViewModel` — which maps to `onSaveInstanceState()` and `onRestoreInstanceState()` — is also useful for a fairly narrow use case:

- User is in your app and does something that you *don't* want to save to disk or the server (e.g., the user didn't click "Save" yet)
- User turns off their phone screen or switches to another app (e.g., via system HOME navigation or the overview screen)
- Time passes
- Android terminates your app process to free up system RAM for other apps
- Within ~30 minutes of having left your app, the user returns to your app

At this point, Android wants to pretend that your app had been around all along, despite the fact that your process had been terminated. So, Android will not only start up a fresh process for you, but it will recreate the last activity the user had been on... and you get your saved instance state back as part of this.

However, this is not a persistence approach. For data you want to have survive long term, you need to save it to disk (SQLite, `SharedPreferences`, JSON file, etc.) or to some server. Notably, if the user leaves your app for an extended period (over ~30 minutes), Android will not attempt to restore the instance state, and your app will be started normally.

Comment: Thanks! that is about as good an answer as I can expect.

I can imagine something like: the fact that a dialog is open might be the kind of thing that might be unimportant after the app has been in the background a long time.

We are splitting hairs about the term "persistence", though --- I see that Android uses it to refer to a specific area of solid-state memory.  The practical questions are: "how long does it persist", "under what circumstances"?  The Lifecycle page is really deficient on this point.

Comment: Android doesn't use swap, so it can't take a process running in memory and store that state on disk to be restored later. Because the system might need to terminate a running process to reclaim memory for another app to use, you have to assume that *will* happen, and store/restore your state accordingly. Callbacks like `onSaveInstanceState` are there to help you do that when you need to. I don't know what the hard guarantees are about how long it's persisted - you should be able to assume it's still there when you need it, until it's no longer needed (e.g. when it's stale state)

Answer (score -1):

You need to use a [`SavedStateHandle`](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel-savedstate) with a `ViewModel` to get data persistence when the system terminates your app in the background. Otherwise it's more about sharing data between components, and surviving `Activity` destruction e.g. on screen rotation without having to do a lot of boilerplate handling.

Just like with `onSaveInstanceState`, this is purely about persisting data *when the system kills your running app to recover memory*, so that when the user switches to the "running" app again, it can be recreated and restored exactly as it was. It doesn't save any data when the app is intentionally stopped, e.g. calling `finish()`, the user backing out or swiping it away etc.

This stuff should always just work - if you were seeing your data "go missing" and the app wasn't crashing in the background, it's possible your save/restore logic wasn't working. A good way to test that is going to *Developer Options* on your device (if you don't know how to get that do a search, it depends on your device) and enable *Don't keep Activities*. That will destroy them as soon as they go to the background and it should help you test how that's handled. The fact you were handling rotations ok suggests it was a background crash though, but that depends on how you were handling configuration changes

Comment: I know how to make the data persist if the user kills the process --- but that wasn't my aim.  My surprise, on following the advice on the page The Activity Lifecycle, that the data was lost randomly.  And why the effect happens was explained in the previous post. It is "normal" behavior --- no crash was involved.  The problem is with the documentation, and with the screwy history of the API.

Comment: @SteveWhite data being lost randomly isn't "normal behaviour", which is why I suggested you were seeing a crash before the "save your state" lifecycle callbacks were happening. `savedInstanceState` has been the way Android handles this since the beginning, back when the callback was called `onFreeze` and the `Bundle` parameter was called `icicle`. Like your *Saving UI States* link says, data saved that way *does* survive process death - that's the whole point to it. `ViewModel`s are relatively new, weren't initially intended for that, but can now do it using `SavedStateHandle`s

Comment: please provide code.  Almost certainly, we are talking past one another.
I think we have established that using the APIs of "The Activity Lifecycle", saving and retrieving Bundles, does NOT preserve data past system-induced process death.  That is just what the table on the page "Saving UI States" asserts.

And now that I understand this, I recognize the behavior in many apps.  Example behavior would be: user picks a filtering of data in a list, puts the app in the background.  If the app isn't brought back immediately, the filtering may be lost.

Comment: @SteveWhite It literally says it right on the page: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/saving-states#options **Saved instance state** *Survives system-initiated process death: Yes*. If you have state that needs saving (beyond the stuff that happens automatically like widget state, e.g. `EditText` contents or whether a `CheckBox` is ticked or not) then it's the *developer's responsibility* to save and restore that state using the provided lifecycle methods, otherwise that state is lost. That's the way it's always worked, you're misunderstanding the documentation

Comment: we are talking about different things.
I am talking about the procedures called in that page "ViewModel",
And under that heading, in the same table you're looking at, it says:
"Survives system-initiated process death: No"

Comment: @SteveWhite yes and ``ViewModel`` is a completely separate *optional* library that was released much more recently and has nothing to do with the Activity lifecycle and its `saveInstanceState` and `restoreInstanceState` callback methods. That's why they're listed on that page as separate things, different approaches that cover different use-cases. You're using them interchangeably and that's why you're misunderstanding the documentation and the explanations people are giving you. In your question you asked "am I missing something" and the answer is yes, but you don't seem to want to hear that

Comment: I am not using saveInstanceState() and restoreInstanceState() interchangeably.  I suppose you mean, I'm using them interchangeably with ViewModel.  But that is incorrect: I only realized that saveInstanceState and restoreInstanceState didn't work as I expected by looking at the column for ViewModel.

If you can show me that those two functions can be used as described in "The Activity Lifecycle", without losing the info saved in the Bundle, I will be grateful and surprised.  The question was about the use-case for these functions, given that behavior.

Comment: @SteveWhite yeah I know that's what the question was about, that's why I kept trying to tell you ViewModels are a completely different, separate thing and you were getting confused. Like I said in my answer, using *SavedInstanceState* is the normal way Android handles saving and restoring running state, and has been since the beginning, because Android doesn't use swap memory. It's not *meant* to lose that state, so if you saw that happen, **that's not expected behaviour** and that's why I'm saying you probably had a crash. You keep arguing like this is just how it's meant to work and it's not